# Avoid using CountDownLatch to wait for many threads before sending the callback

Tags: java, android, multithreading, retrofit, rx-java

So I have a list of Track Ids that for each track Id I need to execute a network request to get the track details,  I am using a for loop to launch all the  requests and a latch to wait for all the requests to be completed. After they are completed then the callback is sent with the List of Tracks that have already populated.

I would like to know if there is any better way to do this, maybe with RxJava ?

I am using Retrofit 2.0 in Android.

```
    public IBaseRequest batchTracksById(final TrackIdList trackIdListPayload, final IRequestListener<TracksList> listener) {
    final TracksList tracks = new TracksList();
    final Track[] trackArray = newrack[trackIdListPayload.getTrackIds().length];
    tracks.setTrack(trackArray);

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(trackArray.length);


    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                latch.await();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        listener.onRequestUpdate(null, tracks, null, true);
                    }
                });

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();

    for (String id : trackIdListPayload.getTrackIds()) {
        getTrackById(id, new IRequestListener<Track>() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestFailure(IBaseRequest request, Exception exception) {
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestUpdate(IBaseRequest request, Track track, RequestState state, boolean requestComplete) {
                //iterate through the tracks and update the ones in the thing

                int i = 0;
                for (String s : trackIdListPayload.getTrackIds()) {
                    if (s.equals(track.getTrackId())) {
                        trackArray[i] = track;
                        // don't break here, as we may have a case where we have multiple instances of the same trackId (although
                        // at the moment a request will be made for each anyway...
                    }
                    i++;
                }

                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make all the requests asynchronously and wait for them to return you can do this (lambdas for brevity and readability):

```
tracks.flatMap(track -> getTrackDetails(track.id)
                          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
      .toList()
      .doOnNext(list -> processTrackList())
      ...
```

If you require that the results are returned in the order of `tracks` but are still requested asynchronously then in soon to be released rxjava 1.0.15 you will be able to do this

```
tracks.concatMapEager(track -> getTrackDetails(track.id)
                          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .toList()
      .doOnNext(list -> processTrackList())
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a list of tracks as input and you want a list of webservice results.  Here's a simple way to do that with RxJava if you can make your network call synchronous (rxjava will handle the background processing for you).

```
 Observable.from(trackList)
                    .map(new Func1<Track, Response>() {
                        @Override
                        public Response call(Track track) {
                            return makeRequestSynchronously(track.id());
                        }
                    })
                    .toList()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Response>>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<Response> responses) {

                        }
                    });
```

Edit:  You can change Retrofit to return observables from webservice, if you do that you will need to change map to the following

```
 .flatMap(new Func1<Track, Observable<Response>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Response> call(Track track) {
                        return makeRequestThatReturnsObservable(track.id());
                    }
                })
```